# PHPExcel Freezepane not working

Tags: php, phpexcel

```
for ($char = 'A'; $char <= 'Z'; $char++) {
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($char.'5','40');
}
for ($i=1;$i<=100;$i++){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$i,generateRandomString());
}
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->freezePane('B');
// Write the PHPExcel object to browser as HTML
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

**$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->freezePane('B');**

Freeze not happened for the " A " (First column) column.

Attached screen shot FYI.[image: showing first column(A Col) details here]
Freeze not happened for the " A " (First column) column.
When i scroll COL A not freeze, col A also hidding.
[image: When i scroll COL A not freeze, col A also hidding.]

Comment: What exactly is not working. At all I think you should select the row too. `freezePane('A1')`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

the freezePane() coordinate should be a cell reference for the top-left cell of the **non-frozen** part of the worksheet, so

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->freezePane('B2');
```

tells Excel to freeze rows above row 2, and to the left of column "B"... i.e. row 1 and column "A" will be frozen.

Comment: This freezpane functionality will work only for xls output, but here trying for HTML Writer , i believe it is not possible for HTML Writer.

Comment: No, it's only supported by the Excel5 and Excel2007 Writers

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$ColumnCount=0;
$RowIndex=8;
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->freezePaneByColumnAndRow($ColumnCount, $RowIndex);
```

Comment: Could you also add an explanation?